# Converting html table to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, quantitative-finance

I have been trying to import a html table from a website and to convert it into a pandas `DataFrame`. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_html("http://www.sharesansar.com/c/today-share-price.html")
dfs = pd.DataFrame(data = table)
print dfs
```

It just displays this:

```
0       S.No                                     ...
```

But if I do;

```
for df in dfs:
    print df
```

It outputs the table..

How can I use **pd.Dataframe** to scrape the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML table on the given url is javascript rendered. `pd.read_html()` doesn't supports javascript rendered pages. You can try with [`dryscrape`](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import dryscrape

s = dryscrape.Session()
s.visit("http://www.sharesansar.com/c/today-share-price.html")
df = pd.read_html(s.body())[5]
df.head()
```

Output:

[image]